# Is Dart's map like a java LinkedHashMap?

Tags: dart

While iterating `forEach` over `Map<String, dynamic>` it seems that it prints always in order. I.e. it behaves like a `LinkedHashMap` in java. The map was decoded from json.

```
data.forEach((k, _) => print(k));
```

The last key from json always prints last. Does it mean it's possible to define the `last` element of the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dart's default implementation for a `Map` is a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap-class.html), which keeps entries in insertion order.  This is mentioned in the documentation for [`Map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map-class.html):

> Map()
> Creates an empty LinkedHashMap.
>
> Map.from(Map other)
> Creates a LinkedHashMap with the same keys and values as `other`.
>
> ...
>
> Map.identity()
> Creates an identity map with the default implementation, LinkedHashMap.